# How to make class an object in angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, class, oop, object

Below is a class `Template`. I want to access its content like this..

```
console.log(this.temp.name);
```

But I can't. Its result is `undefined`. How to make it just an object to be able to access it?

[image]

> Update

In the parent component, I have the code below

`template` is declared as `template = new Template();`

[image]

after the initialization, when I console log template, the value is this
[image]

I then bind `template` to its child component

[image]

but when I console log the value of template in the child component, it became this (the extracted values are the topmost screenshot)

so when I console log `this.template.name` and so on, it is undefined
[image]

Comment: you should make an instance of class and access it, how do you define temp?

Comment: `temp` is declared as `temp = new Template();`

Comment: And how are you setting the `name` of `temp`?

Comment: `this.temp.name = 'sample';` but its undefined in another component. Since I pass it with the use of @Input(). It is undefined in @Input()

Comment: can you post temp component code?

Comment: Yep, please post the relevant code, including where you set the value, and where it is logging as `undefined`.

Comment: posted an uppdate. thanks

Comment: @Char Just so you know, it's usually better if you post the actual code rather than an image. Also, it may help if you post the child component, so we can see where you're logging the value. Even better would be if you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

instead of making Template as class, make it as interface

example:

export interface Template {

/* fields */

}

Answer (score -1):

To instantiate a class, you can either use the new keyword, assign a json structure that is structural compatible to the class definition or if you have a JSON string and want to de serialize it you could use JSON.parse() and assign it to a variable of this type.